# Computer name changes in terminal when connected to Wi-Fi

Tags: terminal

Sorry for my inexperience, I have little experience working with the terminal.

When connected to university wifi, the name changes to something strange that I don't recognize.

[image]

However, when disconnected from wifi, the terminal reads the name of my computer.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what this means or why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish people would search.  I think this gets answered perhaps once a week.

You have configured your shell to display the hostname of the machine in the prompt.

The shell is trying to reverse the computer's IP address to determine the hostname.

When it is connected to your local network, it cannot, so it uses the one you have set in the Sharing pane.

When you are connected to your university wifi, it is successfully able to reverse the IP address to a name, so that is the name it displays.

Comment: Feel free to flag/close as duplicate if you find a question which has been asked before